# Cant seem to read the API data from a google sheet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, api, google-sheets-api

Im using PapaParse to get some data from a Google Sheet to update some on page content. However when i try to parse the data it comes back as multiple arrays and i tried parsing the data but im not sure what im doing wrong here. I included multiple screen shots on what im seeing;

when i try using `JSON.stringify(results)` it just returns what in the array in the last image. i tried doing `results.data.Advertiser` but that didnt help in any way.

here is my code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Papa from "papaparse";

const App = () => {


  const [partners, setPartners] = useState([]);

  Papa.parse("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTWvO-5iopEriD0RMNsxQ0X9psGLAh3NPGjK2GrsrlDxrnRj3tb_I0x1Rs7eeuWo0Pkff0y4JDrl0zQ/pub?output=csv", {
    download: true,
    header: true,
    complete: (results) => {

      console.log(results)
      
      console.log(JSON.stringify(results));

      let p = JSON.stringify(results)

      setPartners(p)
    },
  });

 

  //const part = Array.from(data);


  return (
    <div>
      {partners}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

[image: Console log + how its being rendered based on the state]
[image: The way i have my google sheet]
[image: The response from the api call in multiple arrays]

Comment: What is your expected values in your script?

Comment: what im trying to do is just list them but for some reason it returns each row from the google sheets as an array,

Ex: 

[0 … 99]
``` 0: {Advertiser: 'AAA -- Adam Hukkala -- Hukkala Insurance Agency LL'}
1: {Advertiser: 'AAMedia'}
2: {Advertiser: 'ADG INNOVATIONS'}
3: {Advertiser: 'Advantage Insurance Solutions'}
4: {Advertiser: 'Adventum'}
5: {Advertiser: 'Advisors Insurance Agency'}
6: {Advertiser: 'Agency Incline'}
7: {Advertiser: 'agencyzoom'} ```

Answer (score 0):

What i had to do was literally just get `Array.from(data)` this allowed me to parse the array and map the advertiser side from the google sheets. Here is the full code :

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Papa from "papaparse";

const App = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  Papa.parse("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTWvO-5iopEriD0RMNsxQ0X9psGLAh3NPGjK2GrsrlDxrnRj3tb_I0x1Rs7eeuWo0Pkff0y4JDrl0zQ/pub?output=csv", {

    download: true,
    header: true,
    complete: (results) => {
      setData(results.data)
    }
  })

  const advertisers = Array.from(data);

  console.log(advertisers)


  return (
    <div>
     <ul>
       {advertisers.map((data) =>(
           <li key={data.advertiser}>
             {data.advertiser}
           </li>
       ))}
     </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```